# Some Properties not loaded from server

Tags: spring-boot, properties, microservices, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config-server

So I have been learning microservices with Spring Cloud for a while. I have correctly configured the config server but some properties like the server port and the actuator endpoints are not loaded from config repo. I am obliged to set them locally(*which removes the centralized advantage of config server*).

For example this is the property file in config repo for a service:

```
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address= true
eureka.client.register-with-eureka= true
eureka.client.fetch-registry= true
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone= http://localhost:8761/eureka/
server.port= 5555
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,info,routes
```

My Bootstrap.yml for the same service:

```yaml
spring:
  application:
    name: licensingservice
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:8888
```

This is my pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.thoughtmecanix</groupId>
    <artifactId>api-gateway</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>api-gateway</name>
    <description>A service for the API Gateway</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The Eureka properties are picked up but not the server port and actuator endpoints. I have already searched for the problem but no I have not found a solution to my problem.
Please can someone help me understand why.

Thank you.

Comment: What versions are you using? What is your local configuration?

Comment: @spencergibb I am using spring boot 2.4.4, spring cloud version 2020.2 with spring cloud starter netflix zuul verison 2.2.7 RELEASE

Comment: That is not a supported set of versions, zuul only is supported by boot 2.3.x and spring cloud hoxton. Can you please provide your client configuration?

Comment: @spencergibb I have added the config

Comment: you added your dependencies, but not your configuration (application.yml, bootstrap.yml, etc...)

Comment: I had already provided the application.properties now I have provided the bootstrap file

Comment: I can't say. The only thing bad here is that zuul is NOT supported in spring cloud 2020.0